# javascript from string to array. split my regex

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I need give from text **[{"value":"opa"},{"value":"opa2"},{"value":"opa3"}]**
only opa...
and set it to array like   var array = date.split(regex);
that array[0]="opa" and array[1]="opa2".
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a='[{"value":"opa"},{"value":"opa2"},{"value":"opa3"}]';
var b=JSON.parse(a);

c = [];

b.forEach(function(entry) {
    c.push(entry.value);
});

alert(c[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have array of objets, the task is filter and turn this objets into strings.

```
var array = [{"value":"opa"},{"value":"opa2"},{"value":"o1pa3"}];

array = array.map(function(item){
    if(/opa/.test(item.value)){
      return item.value;
    }
    else return null;
}).filter(function(item){ return item; });

console.log(array)
```

If you want to parse string and convert to JSON object just use

```
var array = JSON.parse(STRING);
```

You can play with [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39tbs/)